# JIBX "Error: Missing required <all>, <choice>..."

Tags: xml, xsd, maven-plugin, jibx

I am using last jibx jars v1.2.3 and maven jibx plugin to generate code from FIXML schemas. I get the following error:

```
Error: Missing required <all>, <choice>, or <sequence> child element for group 'BatchHeaderElements' at (line 69, col 4, in fixml-components-base-4-4-FIA-1-1.xsd)
```

For every single group definition such as:

```
<xs:group name="BatchHeaderElements">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:group>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

JiBX is telling you that you need to specify what elements you want in your sequence. You currently have an empty sequence declaration.
This would be a valid sequence declaration within a group:

```
<xs:group name="BatchHeaderElements">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="GroupName" type="xs:string">
    <xs:element name="GroupDescription" type="xs:string">
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

Hope this helps.
Don Corley
JiBX Maven plugin author

Comment: Yes however this is published schema FIXML that I can't change (http://fixprotocol.org/specifications/fix4.4fixml) . I noticed JAXB generates code without issues. Is this a known problem in JIBX codegen?

Comment: ARR,
This is bad XML. Having a sequence of nothing makes no sense.
JiBX can process most questionable schema definitions, but in cases like this we usually fix the schema definition, then run JiBX.
This can be done on published schema by reading in the schema and running an XSLT (transformation) to fix the problems. There are several examples of this in our standardized schema library. In our schema library, check out the opentravel.org schema and the webservicex schema in our repository at [https://github.com/jibx/schema-library].